# How to map MUI 5 icons from an array of objects and change its color?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have an array of objects which bassically are sidebar items. Every object has a MUI 5 icon. In a sidebar component I render it in a map function. I'd like to have a selected item to be highlighted...I managed to change the font color but don't know how to change icon color.

So the question is how to change icon color in Sidebar.tsx?

**routes.tsx**

```
export const SIDEBAR_PATHS = [
  {
    id: 1,
    path: PATHS.projects,
    name: 'Projects',
    icon: <AccountTreeIcon />,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    path: PATHS.faces,
    name: 'Faces',
    icon: <FaceRetouchingNaturalIcon />,
  },
];
```

**Sidebart.tsx**

```
    {SIDEBAR_PATHS.map(({ id, path, name, icon }) => (
      <ListItem key={id} disablePadding>
        <ListItemButton disableRipple onClick={() => navigate(path)} selected={path === pathname}>
          {icon}
          <ListItemText primary={name} primaryTypographyProps={{ fontWeight: 500 }} />
        </ListItemButton>
      </ListItem>
    ))}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but don't know how to change icon color.

I'd change your `icon` field from `JSX` type (already called react component) to `FC` (a react component) so you can call it later and pass props into it.

Then, just tweak the color of the icon depending on the `selected` prop.

```
export const SIDEBAR_PATHS = [
  {
    id: 1,
    path: PATHS.projects,
    name: 'Projects',
    icon: AccountTreeIcon
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    path: PATHS.faces,
    name: 'Faces',
    icon: FaceRetouchingNaturalIcon,
  },
];

{SIDEBAR_PATHS.map(({ id, path, name, icon }) => {
  const Icon = icon;      

  return (
    <ListItem key={id} disablePadding>
      <ListItemButton disableRipple onClick={() => navigate(path)} selected={path === pathname}>
        <Icon style={{ color: selected ? 'green' : 'red'} />
              //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ toggle the color of icon

        <ListItemText primary={name} primaryTypographyProps={{ fontWeight: 500 }} />
      </ListItemButton>
    </ListItem>
  );
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

For mui 5 you could try this. Mui provides SvgIcon component for the same purpose.

```
import { SvgIcon } from "@mui/material";

....

{SIDEBAR_PATHS.map(({ id, path, name, icon }) => {
  return (
    <ListItem key={id} disablePadding>
      <ListItemButton disableRipple onClick={() => navigate(path)} selected={path === pathname}>
        <SvgIcon style={{ color: path === pathname ? 'green' : 'blue' }}{icon}</SvgIcon>
        <ListItemText primary={name} primaryTypographyProps={{ fontWeight: 500 }} />
      </ListItemButton>
    </ListItem>
  );
})}
```